# NodeMCU v1 keeps dropping out

Tags: nodemcu

I've created a homebridge server on a Raspberry Pi Zero and have configured it to use my NodeMCU v1 (Esp - 12E Module) as an accessory to control RGB strip lights.

All works normally until you don't use the home kit to control the lights for certain amount of time (~30 seconds). My iPhone says that the accessory is non responsive until I force a command to happen, this after some time activates the accessory and goes back to normal.

Is there a way of keeping the NodeMCU active to HTTP responses all the time?

The code I have used is a mashup of a tutorial I used but I've modified it with some more features. (All coded in Arduino)

```cpp
//NodeMCU RGB-Controller for Homebridge & HomeKit (Siri)

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <math.h>

#define redPin 13 //D7 - Red channel
#define grnPin 12 //D6 - Green channel
#define bluPin 14 //D5 - Blue channel
#define white 5 //D1 - Blue channel

WiFiServer server(80); //Set server port

String readString;           //String to hold incoming request
String hexString = "000000"; //Define inititial color here (hex value), 080100 would be a calm warmtone i.e.

int state;

int r;
int g;
int b;

float R;
float G;
float B;

int x;
int V;

///// WiFi SETTINGS - Replace with your values /////////////////
const char* ssid = "xxxxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxxx";
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,234);      // set a fixed IP for the NodeMCU
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);  // Your router IP
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0); // Subnet mask
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void WiFiStart() { 
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet); //Set a fixed IP. You can comment this out and set it in your router instead.
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print("_");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Done");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("");

  server.begin();                    
}

void allOff() {
  state = 0;
  analogWrite(redPin, 0);
  analogWrite(grnPin, 0);
  analogWrite(bluPin, 0);
}

//Write requested hex-color to the pins (10bit pwm)
void setHex() {
  state = 1;
  long number = (long) strtol( &hexString[0], NULL, 16);
  r = number >> 16;
  g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
  b = number & 0xFF;
  r = map(r, 0, 255, 0, 1023);  //added for 10bit pwm
  g = map(g, 0, 255, 0, 1023);  //added for 10bit pwm
  b = map(b, 0, 255, 0, 1023);  //added for 10bit pwm
  analogWrite(redPin, (r));
  analogWrite(grnPin, (g));
  analogWrite(bluPin, (b));
}

//Compute current brightness value

//For serial debugging only
void showValues() {

  Serial.print("Status on/off: ");
  Serial.println(state);
  Serial.print("RGB color: ");
  Serial.print(r);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.print(g);
  Serial.print(".");
  Serial.println(b);
  Serial.print("Hex color: ");
  Serial.println(hexString);

  Serial.print("Brightness: ");
  Serial.println(V);
  Serial.println("");

}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);  //declaration added
  pinMode(grnPin, OUTPUT);  //declaration added
  pinMode(bluPin, OUTPUT);  //declaration added
  setHex(); //Set initial color after booting. Value defined above
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiStart();
  //showValues(); //Uncomment for serial output
}

void loop() {
  //Reconnect on lost WiFi connection (superfluous - will reconnect anyway)
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    WiFiStart();
  }


  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  while(client.connected() && !client.available()) {
    delay(1);
  }

  //Respond on certain Homebridge HTTP requests
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        if (readString.length() < 100) {
          readString += c;
        } 
        if (c == '\n') {
          Serial.print("Request: "); //Uncomment for serial output 
          Serial.println(readString); //Uncomment for serial output

          //Send reponse
         client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();

          //On
          if(readString.indexOf("on") >0) {
            setHex();
            Serial.println("on");
            showValues();
          }

          if(readString.indexOf("xw") >0) {

            Serial.println("won");
            analogWrite(white, 1024);
          }

          if(readString.indexOf("yw") >0) {

            Serial.println("woff");
            analogWrite(white, 0);
          }


          //Off
          if(readString.indexOf("off") >0) {
            allOff();
            showValues();
          }

          //Set color
          if(readString.indexOf("set") >0) {
            hexString = "";
            hexString = (readString.substring(9,15));
            setHex();
            //showValues();
          }

          //Status on/off
          if(readString.indexOf("status") >0) {
          client.println(state);
          }

          //Status color (hex)
          if(readString.indexOf("color") >0) {
          client.println(hexString);
          }

          //Status brightness (%)
          if(readString.indexOf("bright") >0) {

          client.println(V);
          }

          delay(1);
          client.stop();
          readString="";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running out of RAM because you are using the `String` object instead of a fixed-size char[] buffer. This code, in particular:

```
if (readString.length() < 100) {
  readString += c;
}
```

Concatenating `String` objects using the overloaded plus operator allocates a whole new block of RAM for the new, longer string. It frees the previous memory, but since you keep adding one character at a time, new strings won't be able to be put into the once-used RAM.

You should instead use C-style strings (character arrays) and the standard functions for managing them, such as `strnlen()` and `strncat()`, etc. Note, I am suggesting the versions of string functions with a `maxlen` parameter, which helps avoid bugs due to unterminated strings.

Comment: I can't seem to implement this

Comment: Share what you’ve tried. Thus page has a good overview http://www.gammon.com.au/concat

Comment: I had to make a new question as the comment wouldn't let me copy all my changed code: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/nodemcu-keeps-dropping-out-implementation?noredirect=1#comment95555_48066